# Open Chrome in SQL query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-chrome, ssms

How can a query result open directly a Chrome page ?
Specifically, i have some tickets and i need a 2nd column with a hyperlink that opens a Chrome page when i click them from the query results.

```
select TIK.[Id],'https://X.X.X.X/Ticket/Edit?Id='+convert(nvarchar(20),TIK.[Id]) as 'Link'
from TICKET as TIK
```

I tried this way:

```
    select TIK.[Id],cast('https://X.X.X.X/Ticket/Edit?Id='+convert(nvarchar(20),TIK.[Id]) as XML) as 'Link'   
from TICKET as TIK
```

but the link only opens a new query tab.

Some help please ?

Thanks,

kostas

**Found the solution by adding the SSMSBoost add-in and with visualize option, it works like a charm. 
Thanks

Comment: this is neither a sql-problem, nor a google-chrome-problem

Comment: Which tags are appropriate for SQL Queries ? Ty for the feedback.

Comment: Don't write the solution in the question...add it to the Answers section below. Then others can find it in search results and also vote on it. That's how this site works. You're allowed to answer your own question!